# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, typeerror

this unfinished piece of code is intended to return the sum of of letters if 1 to x were written out in words:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def Base1(n):
  if (n==1):
      return len('one') 
  if (n==2):
    return len('two') 
  if (n==3):
      return len('three')
  if (n==4):
      return len('four') 
  if (n==5):
      return len('five') 
  if (n==6):
      return len('six') 
  if (n==7):
      return len('seven') 
  if (n==8):
      return len('eight')
  if (n==9):
      return len('nine')
def Base10(g):
  if (g == 10):
    return len('ten')
  if (g == 11):
    return len('eleven')
  if (g == 12):
    return len('twelve')
  if (g == 13):
    return len('thirteen')
  if (g == 14):
    return len('fourteen')
  if (g == 15):
    return len('fifteen')
  if (g == 16):
    return len('sixteen')
  if (g == 17):
    return len('seventeen')
  if (g == 18):
    return len('eightteen')
  if (g == 19):
    return len('nineteen')
  if (g == 20):
    return len('twenty')
  if (g > 20):
    return BiggerThan20(g)
def BiggerThan20(t):
  if t<30:
    return len('twenty')+Base1(t-20)
  if t<40:
    return len('twenty')+Base1(t-20)


def trial(runcounter):
  summitup = 0
  if (len(str(runcounter))==1):
    summitup += Base1(runcounter)
  if (len(str(runcounter))==2):
    summitup += Base10(runcounter)
  return summitup

lettersum = 0

start = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
for k in range(1, start+1, 1):
  lettersum += trial(k)
 #print (k, lettersum)
print(lettersum)
```

It runs fine up to 29, but if I enter anything >= 30 bash returns following output:

```
opq@home:/home/opq/python pe17.py

Please enter an integer: 32

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pe17.py", line 65, in <module>
    lettersum += trial(k)
  File "pe17.py", line 58, in trial
    summitup += Base10(runcounter)
  File "pe17.py", line 45, in Base10
    return BiggerThan20(g)
  File "pe17.py", line 50, in BiggerThan20
    return len('twenty')+Base1(t-20)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

I am new to programming and unsure why this error occurs.

Base1 seems suddenly to return None when the first if-statement in BiggerThan20 turns false.

I appreciate any help you may provide.

Solved!
I forgot to care for the tens...
Thank you for your help

Comment: `Base1(t-20)` -> `Base1(12)` which returns `None` because you have not handled cases for inputs > 9 in `Base1`.

Comment: As a matter of style, you should not use parenthesis in your if statements.  `if n == 1:` is preferred.

Comment: Also, your chain of if statements should probably use `elif` after the first `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Base1` does not return anything for number 10 or greater number.

```
>>> Base1(1)
3
>>> Base1(10) # None
>>> Base1(20) # None

>>> len('twenty') + Base1(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

`Base10`, `BiggerThan20` have same problem.

- `Base10` does not return for numbers less than 10.
- `BiggerThan20` does not return for number >= 40.

Answer (score 0):

falsetru is correct.

perhaps you want this:

```
if t<40:
return len('twenty')+Base1(t-20)
```

to be:

```
if t<40:
return len('thirty')+Base1(t-30)
```

Comment: Thank you, but that produced the same error code. I actually forgot the case of 30...